# Unable to export ec2 instance to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to export an EC2 instance (instance created with AMI which was imported earlier using VM import export service) to S3 bucket which is constantly failing . I also tried changing the bucket access to public still the error continues . I used both python SDK and CLI commands where both returns the same error

CLI used:

```
aws ec2 create-instance-export-task --instance-id i-***** --target-environment vmware --export-to-s3-task file://C:\file.json
```

json file containing bucket and VM image details

> Error :An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the
> CreateInstanceExportTask operation: vm-import-export@amazon.com must
> have WRITE and READ_ACL permission on the S3 bucket.

I'm not able to add vm-import-export@amazon.com as a grantee .

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Attach an access control list (ACL) to your S3 bucket containing the following grant**:

- grantee: c4d8eabf8db69dbe46bfe0e517100c554f01200b104d59cd408e777ba442a322
- permissions: READ and WRITE

More information at [Exporting an Instance as a VM Using VM Import/Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html).

** unless you're targeting an S3 bucket in Bahrain, Hong Kong, Beijing, or GovCloud (US-West), which have different grantees, see the docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot , It works . Can i please know the details of  grantee information (canonical ID)  you have provided . Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, beyond the document that I referred you to. The grantee is the canonical account ID of an AWS account associated with the import/export service.

Answer (score 3):

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket bucket_name --grant-read id="alphanumeric-id-string"

aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket bucket_name --grant-write id="alphanumeric-id-string"
```

You can use the alphanumeric-id-string from this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html

**Choose by your region:**
i.e for *All other Regions*

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket bucket_name --grant-read id="c4d8eabf8db69dbe46bfe0e517100c554f01200b104d59cd408e777ba442a322"
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to resolve this issue

1. login to your AWS Management Console. [AWS console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ESKS.png)
2. Select S3 under AWS services/All service
3. Click on the bucket name you created or create bucket if you have not created one
4. Click on Permissions tab and scroll to Access control list (ACL) and click Edit  [ACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmmXo.png)
5. Click Add grantee button and paste **c4d8eabf8db69dbe46bfe0e517100c554f01200b104d59cd408e777ba442a322** in the canonical id box [canonical id for all region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU2x9.png)
6. Grant Write access to Objects and Read access to Bucket ACL [Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R0gK.png)
7. Saves changes and run the command on your machine

aws ec2 create-instance-export-task --instance-id i-***** --target-environment vmware --export-to-s3-task file://C:\file.json

8. If you see error message "Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure"

You can check and copy your temporary credential on your aws login page and paste it on your terminal and hit enter [temporary credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RC17.png). Rerun

aws ec2 create-instance-export-task --instance-id i-***** --target-environment vmware --export-to-s3-task file://C:\file.json

Ref. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bsmn_UX3vww

Answer (score 0):

Making the S3 Bucket Public just grants access to Read its contents.

What you're trying to do is to create an object on S3.

Based on the error you're getting the destination bucket must grant WRITE and READ_ACL permissions to the vm-import-export@amazon.com AWS account.